# Java Postfix Expression Evaluator

Tags: java

I really need help with my post-fix expression calculator. I don't really know what's wrong with the code that I've written, however when I run the program, it just prints whatever number is on the top. For example, if I input "7 2 +", the output is 2. If I input "2 7 +", the output is 7. Could somebody please point me in the right direction on how to fix this? I think (not sure) that the problem is that my program is not able to properly detect the operands "+" and "*". However, I can't tell why.

File #1:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ProblemTwo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a post value expression: ");
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input);
        Stack hello = new Stack(st.countTokens());

        for (int i = 0; i <= st.countTokens(); i++) {
            String inputToken = st.nextToken();
            if (inputToken.trim().contains("+")) {
                int sum = Integer.parseInt(hello.pop() + Integer.parseInt(hello.pop()));
                System.out.println(sum);
                hello.push(Integer.toString(sum));
            }
            else if (inputToken.trim().contains("*")){
                int product = Integer.parseInt(hello.pop()) * Integer.parseInt(hello.pop());
                hello.push(Integer.toString(product));
            }
            else {
                hello.push(inputToken);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(hello.pop());
    }
}
```

File #2:

```
public class Stack {

        private String[] stackArray;
        private int arraySize;
        private int top;

        public Stack(int capacity) {
            arraySize = capacity;
            stackArray = new String[arraySize];
            top = -1;
        }

        public void push(String i) {
            stackArray[++top] = i;
        }

        public String pop() {
            return stackArray[top--];
        }

        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return top == -1;
        }

        public boolean isFull() {
            return top == arraySize - 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `return stackArray[top--];` in `pop()`?

Comment: Is there a reason to maintain a stack of `String` instead of `int`s?

Comment: @Sudhir Singh Yeah you're right, I just changed it but it's still the same error

Comment: @Clashoft Yeah, I want to be able to use the StringTokenizer method & scan.nextLine() to read the entire line, however I don't think it would make a difference in detecting the + or * would it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has at least 2 problems:
Your took not all inputed value in for loop and your stack has broken implementation.
Here is working version.

File #1:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ProblemTwo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a post value expression: ");
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input);
        Stack hello = new Stack(st.countTokens());

        for (int i = 0; i <= st.countTokens()+1; i++) {
            String inputToken = st.nextToken();
            if (inputToken.trim().contains("+")) {
                int sum = Integer.parseInt(hello.pop()) + Integer.parseInt(hello.pop());
                System.out.println(sum);
                hello.push(Integer.toString(sum));
            }
            else if (inputToken.trim().contains("*")){
                int product = Integer.parseInt(hello.pop()) * Integer.parseInt(hello.pop());
                hello.push(Integer.toString(product));
            }
            else {
                hello.push(inputToken);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(hello.pop());
    }
}
```

File #2:

```
public class Stack {

    private String[] stackArray;
    private int arraySize;
    private int top;

    public Stack(int capacity) {
        arraySize = capacity;
        stackArray = new String[arraySize];
        top = -1;
    }

    public void push(String i) {
        stackArray[++top] = i;
    }

    public String pop() {
        return stackArray[top--];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return top == -1;
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return top == arraySize - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: @OlegBaranenko I don't think this is right answer as it is just a hack in this particular case. If you would have input like: `1 2 + 3 +` this loop will fail. Besides use of  variable `i` is useless in this scenario.

Comment: @SudhirSingh, yes I agree with you, it was a quick fix.
However problem places was showing correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is you are using `st.countTokens()` in `for` loop but each subsequent call to `countTokens()` *returns count of the number of times this tokenizer's `nextToken` method can be called*. From [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#countTokens--)'s doc:

> Calculates the number of times that this tokenizer's nextToken method
>   can be called before it generates an exception. The current position
>   is not advanced.

Use another variable to capture `st.countTokens()` before starting loop or better use `st.hasMoreTokens()` for terminating loop. Like:

```
while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
 // same logic
}
```

Also modify `pop()` method to return `stackArray[top--];`.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Stack;
public class Postfix_Eva {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String exp="231*+9-";//giving input
    System.out.println(eva(exp));//calling eva method with argument exp(String)
}

static int eva(String e)
{
    Stack stk=new Stack();//creating object for Stack
    for(int i=0;i<e.length();i++)
    {
        char c=e.charAt(i); //retriving each character from String using .charAt() method
        if(Character.isDigit(c)) //checking whether the character is digit or not
        {
            //Casting is not done
            stk.push(c-'0');

        }
        else
        {
            int a=(int) stk.pop(); //casting popped value into int
            int b=(int) stk.pop();
            switch(c)
            {
                case '+': 
                stk.push(a+b); 
                break; 

                case '-': 
                stk.push(a-b); 
                break; 

                case '/': 
                stk.push(a/b); 
                break; 

                case '*': 
                stk.push(a*b); 
                break; 
            }
        }
    }
    return (int) stk.pop();//returning int casted value of stk.pop() 
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation

Comment: I think this would be fine by now @Sfil_81